# how the grass-gis extension r.diversity work?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, grass-7.2

I have found a nice [paper](https://www.faunalia.eu/pdf/ECOINF_2013.pdf) about `r.diversity` extension. But I don't understand why... it returns me empty raster without errors.

I have tried to compute diversity on ndvi from spot6 image...

```
r.diversity --verbose --overwrite input=SPOT6_P_20151113@PERMANENT prefix=div_ size=3-11
```

a `r.info` on one of these readers give me

```
r.info map=div__pielou_size_3@unsup_class                                       
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Map:      div__pielou_size_3@unsup_clas  Date: Wed Apr  5 17:55:41 2017    |
 | Mapset:   unsup_class                    Login of Creator: delaye          |
 | Location: spot                                                             |
 | DataBase: /home/delaye/Documents/futurSahel/grassDB                        |
 | Title:    div__pielou_size_3                                               |
 | Timestamp: none                                                            |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |                                                                            |
 |   Type of Map:  raster               Number of Categories: 0               |
 |   Data Type:    DCELL                                                      |
 |   Rows:         811                                                        |
 |   Columns:      825                                                        |
 |   Total Cells:  669075                                                     |
 |        Projection: UTM (zone 28)                                           |
 |            N: 1766650.21572733    S: 1765434.19215405   Res: 1.49941254    |
 |            E: 468559.15364472    W: 467321.45407192   Res: 1.50024191      |
 |   Range of data:    min = -nan  max = -nan                                 |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Data Description:                                                        |
 |    gnr par r.li.pielou                                                     |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Comments:                                                                |
 |    r.li.pielou --overwrite input="SPOT6_NDVI_20151113@unsup_class" conf\   |
 |    ig="conf_diversity_3" output="div__pielou_size_3"                       |
 |                                                                            |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How it works ? Regarding the paper I don't need a conf file for r.li ...

Comment: [GRASS GIS manual: r.diversity](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/addons/r.diversity.html)

Comment: Of course I have read the manual :-) but I don't interstate why all the raster results are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found the solution. I was working on the image in 16 bit. So after a `r.rescale` as

```
r.rescale input=cut_LC82040492015257LGN00_B2.1@PERMANENT output=cut_LC82040492015257LGN00_B2.1.resc to=0,255
```

it works like a charm

```
r.diversity input=cut_LC82040492015257LGN00_B8.1.resc@PERMANENT prefix=div size=3-13
```

[image: pielou analyse]